# React Data Table Component Sort Arrows Always Visible

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I have a react data table component ([https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)) where I would like the sorting icons in the header cells to always be visible. The default behavior is that the sort arrows are hidden until you hover over them or enable one of them.

I have done some investigating and messing around in the browser inspect tool and have found that changing the opacity property for a specific span will acheieve what I want but I don't know how to access it in code.

Here is how I am rendering my data table component

```
    <DataTable
      customStyles={agentTableCustomStyles}
    />
```

And here is my agentTableCustomStyles file

```
const agentTableCustomStyles = {
  rows: {
    style: {
      minHeight: '72px',
      textAlign: 'right',
      opacity: '1'
    }
  },
  headCells: {
    style: {
      fontSize: '20px',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      paddingLeft: '0 8px',
      // justifyContent: 'center',
      opacity: '1'
    },
  },
  cells: {
    style: {
      fontSize: '20px',
      paddingLeft: '0',
      // justifyContent: 'center'
    },
  },
};
```

How it looks currently:

[image: How it looks currently]

Here's what I want when I change this opacity property:
[image: Here's what I want when I change this opacity property:]

Answer (score 2):

can't find any prop in documentation but you can use this class to hide using CSS.

```
    .rdt_TableCol_Sortable span {
       display:none
     }
```

it will hide span inside *rdt_TableCol_Sortable* class

Comment: Thank you, this helped me yield what I wanted to achieve. I just changed from display to opacity and set the opacity to 1.